# How to show what is going on if we drop significiant variable in logit model?

Tags: regression, probability, estimation, logit

How to show what is going on if we drop significant variable in logit model ? Bias and heteroskedasticity should emerge. But what is the framework for showing such behaviours in econometric models ?

Answer (score 2):

This depends heavily upon the nature of the experiment and how the data were obtained. In a causal modeling framework, you would adjust for possible confounding variables, factors which are associated with the outcome and causally related to the exposure/predictor of interest. Also, you might adjust for prognostic factors to get individual level treatment effect levels.

When you use robust standard errors, there is no "bias" in reduced logit models that omit any of these adjustment variables. You are instead just estimating a "marginal" model. The interpretation of the main effect (an adjusted odds ratio) changes by the inclusion/omission of these factors. The choice of which model to present for inference should be part of a prespecified analysis plan and not obtained through some "hypothesis generating" model selection techniques such as AIC stepwise model selection, LASSO, or bagging/boosting.

Lastly, there is no concept of heteroscedasticity in logit models because the mean-variance relationship is specified by the link function. You may be referring to dispersion however, again this is an issue that robust standard errors would address.

Comment: Standard errors are quite biased low if one removes "insignificant" predictors.  Less clear is what happens with removal of "significant" predictors.  I think it is fair to say that the $\beta$s of the remaining variables will be biased (due to non-collapsability of odds ratios), so that even correct SEs will be SEs of the wrong quantities.

Comment: Interesting comment, @FrankHarrell. I think collapsability and the bias of odds ratios and their estimates is relevant when we can specify a true model and think of other models as false. However, "all models are false, some models are useful". With GEE (logistic regression using robust standard errors), linear models with omitted covariates give parameter estimates that are consistent and unbiased for population averaged odds ratios. Wald based inference is of the right level. The distinction is that the marginal model parameters cannot estimate the analagous correct model parameters.

Comment: I'd have to disagree rather sharply with that logic.  The fact that we never know the true model is not directly relevant because it's a matter of degree, i.e., of getting closer to the true model.  And population averaged odds ratios have no interpretation.  Mitch Gail published an example where the conditional odds ratios for X=0 and X=1 are both 9 but the unconditional (on sex) odds ratio is 5.4 which is not an average of 9 and 9.

Comment: I disagree that population averaged odds ratios have no interpretation. I do think such odds ratios (crude/population averaged) cannot compare directly to stratified/adjusted odds ratios as from MH or adjusted/conditional logit reg. They have different interpretations. "Population averaged" shouldn't mean the average of the individual level causal effects; this is a direct consequence of collapsibility as you've pointed out. This doesn't meant that such ORs are useless. In public policy, an outreach may  be effective in "borderline" people, but overall does not show large effect sizes.

Comment: I'll likely change my opinion if you can give an exact comprehensible definition of the crude/population averaged estimates.